# Change Number of Channel to a fixed value for 4d shape images

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

My current input shape is `[4, 3, 32, 32]` and I want to reduce the second parameter to `1` which will eventually become `[4, 1, 32, 32]`.
Are there any methods that can achieve this using numpy?
Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the function you want to use for reduction. Usually the `ufunc` `add` or `sum` is used to reduce axis. `Keepdims=True` will ensure keeping the 4 axis intact after reduction. -

```
x = np.random.random((4, 3, 32, 32))

np.add.reduce(x,1,keepdims=True)
#(4,1,32,32)

x.sum(1, keepdims=True)
#(4,1,32,32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am probably guessing this is to convert a batch of RGB images to grayscale images.
 For that you'd have to define a way you'd like to do the conversion. 
A common way is to simply average the three values.
Using numpy, you can do this like so:

```py
# axis is the channel over which you'll take the mean
# keepdims ensures you don't lose any dimensions in the process

image_batch.shape             # [batch_size, channels, height, width]

greyscale_image_batch = numpy.mean(image_batch, axis=1, keepdims=True)

greyscale_image_batch.shape   # [batch_size, 1, height, width]
```